# Linux kernel source code: how to switch from longterm to stable?

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, samsung-galaxy

i have downloaded source code of Linux kernel from Samsung Open Source center for my Samsung Galaxy Grand Prime device (sm-g530fz). Kernel version is 3.10.49 which is longterm kernel from 2014. I want to upgrade this kernel to the latest (5.0) by git cherry-pick, version by version. I don't know that i schould upgrade to 3.10.50, 3.10.51, 3.10.52 and so on to 3.10.108 and then to 3.11 because there are longterm and different than stable kernels. I've noticed that on the same day that 3.10.49 was released, 3.4.99, 3.15.6 (propably stable), 3.14.13 was also released. Thanks for any help.